# How do I write hairpins and dynamics between staves in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond, engraving, dynamics

Here's a minimal example of the sort of result I want to produce in LilyPond. (This was produced in Finale.)

[image]

Notice that the crescendo-stop, *f*, and decrescendo-start align with a note in the bottom staff only and the decrescendo-stop and last *p* align with a note in the top staff only.

Here's the best approximation I can write in LilyPond with its output.

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "english"

\new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff {
        \clef "treble"
        \time 3/4
        \relative c'' {c4 \p \< c2 | c4 c2 \p}
    }
    \new Staff {
        \clef "bass"
        \relative c' {r4 r4 c4~ \f \> | c2 r4 \!}
    }
>>
```

[image]

Notice that each hairpin doesn't terminate at the dynamic marking in the other staff. I'm not surprised by that output, I just don't know how to get the output I want.

The example I'm giving here is just a toy to illustrate the type of problem I'm facing in many much more complex passages.

Is there a standard solution for connecting dynamics between staves in LilyPond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I typically solve this problem by using a separate `\new Dynamics` entry. I find that this a) helps align the dynamics more easily with staff objects, and b) aligns the dynamics vertically as opposed to having them be various distances from the staff.

```
\version "2.20.0"
\language "english"

\new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff {
        \clef "treble"
        \time 3/4
        \relative c'' {c4 c2 | c4 c2 }
    }
    \new Dynamics {
      s4\p s\< s\!\f\> |
      s s\p
    }
    \new Staff {
        \clef "bass"
        \relative c' {r4 r4 c4~ | c2 r4 }
    }
>>
```

This produces:

[image]

Obviously you can tweak horizontal spacing to lengthen some of these hairpins, etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you!

Comment: `\!\f` is unnecessary; stating a new dynamic automatically closes an open hairpin

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Oh, wow; how did I never realize that? Thanks, those are spots that I always have to think through when inputting the code, so this will save me untold headaches moving forward!